# How to pass a collection name as an argument into methods in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Thanks my poor English skill, I have o express my idea by these code below..

**Friendly edit:**

I am trying to write a generalized `confirmAndRemoveCollection` method which takes in the `collectionName` and `itemId`, and I would like to perform operations on this collection. Since `collectionName` is a string, I wouldn't be able to perform DB operations on it. Could someone please suggest how I could use the collection name to get access to the actual collection object.

```
confirmAndRemoveCollection:(collectionName,itemId)->
    check(itemId,String)
    check(collectionName,String)
    sweetAlert({
            title:"confirm"
            text:"blabla"
            type:"info"
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "delete"
            cancelButtonText: "cancel"
            closeOnConfirm: false,
        },(isConfirm)->
        if isConfirm
            collectionName.remove(itemId)
        else
            return
        swal(
            'success'
            "selected item deleted"
            "success"
        )
```

Comment: Is the "collection" going to be a collection of key-value properties (i.e. an object) or a collection of objects (i.e. an array)?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `collectionName` is a string object, so you won't be able to call MongoDB methods on it.

One way to accomplish your task is to create an object that maps the string name to the collection object.

For example:

`Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');
Comments = new Mongo.Collection('comments');
Collections = {
  'Posts': Posts,
  'Comments': Comments
};`

Then you could do something like this in your code

```
if isConfirm
  Collections[collectionName].remove(itemId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an alternative here (even though the question is really old): you can pass the collection itself as an argument and it will work.

As the collection is an Object, when you pass it as an argument it will be passed "by reference" and you will be able to call its methods.

Following the example by @FullStack (which also works, of course):

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');
Comments = new Mongo.Collection('comments');

const collectionRemove = (collection, id) => {
    const count = collection.remove(id);
    console.log(`Removed ${count} items with id ${id} from collection ${collection._name}`)
}
```

And then do something like:

```
collectionRemove(Posts, 1);
collectionRemove(Comments, 24);
```